# Cubic residue symbol

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ a prime number, $ p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

If $$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)_3 = 1,$$ why does there always exist a prime number $q$, where $q \nmid 3p$ and $q \equiv -1 \pmod 3$, such that $$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)_3 \neq 1?$$

Recall that $$\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)_3 = 1 \iff X^3 \equiv c \ \pmod p$$ resolved on $$\mathbb{Z} \iff c^{\frac{p - 1}{3}} \equiv 1 \pmod p,$$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Say we have two numbers, $n$ and $m$ such that $n^3\equiv m^3\equiv 1\pmod p$. Now $n^3-m^3\equiv 0 \equiv (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\pmod p$. Maybe you can use this to get an upper bound on how many residues there are below $p$? (because either $a-b$ or $a^2+ab+b^2$ is divisible by $p$) If there's only a few residus, then there should be lots of primes that aren't residues.

Comment: There are $\frac{p-1}{3}$ cubic residues modulo $p$ (not counting $0$). If $3$ is a cubic residue, it follows that there is at least one cubic nonresidue $a \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. Find a prime $q \equiv a \pmod{3p}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer and Mastrem Thanks.